# SSRS using an expression to sum a set of rows in a table

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I am using SSRS Reports and need to add an expression in a table that sums values in a column based on a value in the dataset.
I believe the `SUM` function would work but I can't figure out how to use the expression part of the function to limit the sums to a value in the dataset.
The dataset, `PatientRevenue` has a column `FullCharges` that I want to sum when the value in the column in the dataset `GroupName` is `Private`.
I don't want the group name to appear in the table so I just added a `Total` row and want to add expressions in the cells to sum the rows.
The expression I have that does not work is:
`=Sum(Fields!FullCharge.Value, [GroupName] = "Private")`
How do I set the expression in the `SUM` function to only sum values with a `GroupName = Private`?

Comment: SSRS doesn't use VBScript, it's powered by .Net so you likely mean VB.Net.

Comment: [Expressions (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs) - *"Expressions are written in **Microsoft Visual Basic**, saved in the report definition, and evaluated by the report processor when you run the report."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not tested this but I think it should be OK.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!GroupName.Value ="Private", Fields!FullCharge.Value, Nothing))
```